# creation of jar files for selected packages using maven

Tags: maven

I have requirement to generate jar files for selected packages i am new to maven  I am able to create jar for **src** folder but unable use  and  tags .I have spent almost 3 days i haven't got the solution.Please help me by provide good solution or porm.xml file

Thanks in Advance,
Regards
Sai.

Comment: Look into [maven modules](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects)

Comment: Are we talking about sources or classes?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.apmc.sphbn</groupId>
 <artifactId>APMC</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>APMC</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 

 <properties>
  <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
  <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
  <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
  <context.path>APMC</context.path>
  
 </properties>
 
 <build>
  <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>

  <plugins>
   <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>${jdk.version}</source>
     <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>${log4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.6</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     
     <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
     </dependency>
       
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20141113</version>
  </dependency>
     
  <!-- Spring Security -->  
  <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
       
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
 
  <!-- JSON Object -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20141113</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- Jackson Object -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>
  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```